# Using backends again on AppEngine (instead of modules)

Tags: google-app-engine

I have tried to use the module feature instead of backends on AppEngine without success (and without any support from Google).

So I am now trying to rollback.

How do I remove modules uploaded, so that I can activate my backend once again.

I get

```
  Error 400: 
     --- begin server output ---
     Your app may not have more than 2 modules.  Please remove one of the existing mo
     dules by deleting all of its versions before trying to create a new module.
    --- end server output ---
```

when trying to

appcfg.py update --backends .

I even tried to use a new version number (and deleted the old version) without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you delete all of the versions on your non-default module, you'll be able to deploy your backends again.

Comment: how can I remove the non-default module?